# Find the top player for the team in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to find only top player for the team ?

Sample data is

```
PlayerID TeamID Count
1        1      7
2        1      2
3        2      3
4        2      5
5        3      7
6        3      6
```

I want to select only 1 Player with top count for each team

```
PlayerID TeamID Count
1        1      7
4        2      5
5        3      7
```

Comment: What if two or more players on the same team have the same count?

Comment: Then anyone from the same team will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` window function to number rows according to score for each team:

```
with cte as (
    select *, r = row_number() over (partition by teamid order by count desc)
    from score_table
)
select * from cte where r = 1;
```

There are also the functions `rank` and `dense_rank` that would be usable (they handles ties differently).

To see how `rank` and `dense_rank` handles ties and ranking, consider this example:

```
Player  Score rank dense_rank
1       5     1    1
2       5     1    1
3       4     3    2
```

See this article for more information: [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use this query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
 LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
  ON  t1.TeamID = t2.TeamID 
  AND t1.[Count] < t2.[Count]
WHERE 
    (t2.PlayerID IS NULL);
```